802.11n USB wifi adapter (LM Technologies LM816-0648-3 Realtek 00E04C0001) crashes system
I have a desktop running Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS with kernel 6.2.0-1018-lowlatency,
with a LM Technologies LM816-0648-3 Realtek 00E04C0001 802.11n NIC USB wifi adapter.
Wifi use locks the system (display, mouse, keyboard unresponsive). By default the r8188eu driver was loaded, but I see the same behavior with the rtl8188fu driver.
How do I get a stable wifi connection on this device, while ensuring the machine does not crash?

Attempted resolution
It's not a driver conflict: On my system lsmod showed both r8152 and r8188eu drivers active (r8152 for the motherboard ethernet not needed). I ran rmmod r8152 and added blacklist r8152 to  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf; The r8152 driver is no longer active, but wifi use still crashes my system.
It's not a coincidence: I've since run the machine for a few hours without the adapter attached; It remains responsive. Restoring the adapter and using wifi data again locks the system.
The rtl8188fu driver gives similar behavior. Per /u/rykr's suggestion I tested the rtl8188fu following these installation steps. The behavior is the same.
Related questions etc. that don't resolve this:
Many questions deal with adapters not working, rather than locking the system. Few mention this device;
Many concern support for internal/onboard wifi chipsets, but it's hard to determine which to this USB wifi device in June of 2024.
This question has the same symptoms but I don't understand the answer;
This unanswered question reports a kernel panic on an rπ with the same USB adapter, unclear if related;
This open issue on the rtl8188eu driver github seems similar but has no follow-up.

Have you tried this driver out? I was having issues getting that same wifi driver to work on a real-time kernel and this worked for me on Debian 12: https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu
I hope it helps.

Thank you /u/rykr; Unfortunately, I'm seeing the same behavior with this driver. And, when it is working (before it locks the system), it disconnected at random and the data rates are terrible in a way I don't think can be cleanly attributed to a weaker radio.
